# Generic way to get prev/next search results by id in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have a million (many) documents in my index. I execute a search query sorting the items by some key X.

Now I have a very long list of results: `[..., id1, id2, id3, ...]`

Question: how do I get `id1` and `id3` if I know `id2` but don't want to execute the whole search/don't want to get all ids?

**I'm looking of a generic solution that works for any search query. Given an id that for certain exists in the results of a query, how to get prev/next by that id. The query should NOT have prior knowledge of anything else than the id whose prev/next are searched for.** (In other words, if ordered by title and searched for prev/next of id X, the title of X is not known at query time, only X's id.)

It is of course possible to execute multiple search queries and achieve the same end result by getting `id2` and then playing with ordering to get ids 1 and 3.

EDIT:
I think Luc E's answer isn't what I'm looking for. In that scenario, knowledge of the original objects title is required to query for prev/next. I'm looking for a solution where only the id is known at query time.

Example data looks like this:

```
[...
{id: 32, title: 'AAA'},
{id: 12, title: 'BBB'},
{id: 99, title: 'CCC'},
{id: 3, title: 'DDD'},
{id: 1001, title: 'EEE'},
...]
```

What I know: id 99. What I don't know: what is title of id 99.
What I want: ids of the prev/next items sorted by title field (=3 and 12).

To put it yet another way: I have id 99 but not the title in my hand. I want a query that gives me ids 3 and 12 (they are prev/next sorted by title).

Comment: So what i know is that results of search query returns a dict, and in python's context, let `res = es.search(index="test-index", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})`,  if say you access `res['hits']['hits']`, you can access each result using the index (i.e. `res['hits']['hits'][0]` will return you the first result of your search query). So is there any way you can get the index of id2? If so then you'd be able to get id1 and id3 by looking for `res['hits']['hits'][n-1]` and  `res['hits']['hits'][n+1]` where `n` is the index of id2

Comment: @user12758604, sadly no. Getting the index of `id2` is not possible. Thank you for your suggestion but it isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: How are you identifying which of the result is to be `id2` at the moment?

Comment: @user12758604 I know the document id – or some other identifying information – of `id2`. So I have that exact knowledge before executing the search query.

Comment: I'm not sure how the performance will work with an excessively large result, but i'm thinking you can get the index of `id2` by iterating through the result, something like
`for pos, item in enumerate(response['hits']['hits']):
     if item['_source']['someKey']=="keyOfid2":
         index_of_id2 = pos;
         break;` (I know python doesn't need semi colon but I can't break line in comments, sorry!) , then apply the approach I shared with you earlier. Not much other ways I could help, sorry!

Comment: @user12758604, yes, I understand =) The whole point here was *NOT* to iterate over the results or fetch all ids, as I said already in the question description. Thank you for your effors!

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is called `deep scrolling`, you have only two ways to make it :

1. [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-scroll)
2. [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-search-after)

The easiest way is the [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-search-after) but you will need to make two requests :

- one request for `id3`
- Another one for `id1`

So, in this example I am looking for `id2 : 128`. I can sort documents with the field `title` and I have get beforehand the value of `title` for `id2` which is `title_of_128`.

To perform the `search_after`, I have to add the `_id` on a sub sort condition

Here is my query :

```
POST test/_search
{
  "size": 2,
  "search_after": ["title_of_128","128"],
  "sort": [
    {
      "title": {
        "order": "asc"
      },
      "_id": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The result of this query is `id2` and `id3`

Now I inverse the direction of the sort in order to retrieve the `id1` :

```
POST test/_search
{
  "size": 2,
  "search_after": ["title_of_128","128"],
  "sort": [
    {
      "title": {
        "order": "desc"
      },
      "_id": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The result of this query is `id2` and `id1`

Note that sort with `_id` is deprecated and the best practice is to copy the `_id` in another field if you want to use `search_after`

Comment: If I understand this correctly, I cannot do this kind of a search without _prior knowledge_ of the `id1`'s title, right? If I *only have* the actual id value of `id1` (not the title of `id1`), I cannot ask for next item sorted by title, right?

Comment: Yes you understand well. The search_after parameter must specify what is in the `sort`, in the same order . So if you don't have the value of `id1`'s title you will need to get it with a query. The only other way to do what you want is to use the scroll method which could be a better solution because in one hand there will be only one scan of the index but in the other hand there will be more network exchanges. You can look about Sliced Scroll too.